# How can i run perl "prove" using maven's pom.xml

Tags: perl, maven

There is a little know plugin on codehaus that will run any [bsf](http://jakarta.apache.org/bsf/) language:

```
svn checkout https://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/trunk/sandbox/script-maven-plugin .
```

That combined with [bsfperl](http://bsfperl.sourceforge.net/) can be used to run perl scripts.

There is also :

```
http://www.ohloh.net/p/maven-perl-plugin
```

Other than these i could not find any information or examples  on how to run [prove](http://perldoc.perl.org/App/Prove.html)

Comment: The information in SVN shows that the last commit has been done in 2009. So a little bit out of date. The question is what you like to achieve with Maven in relationship with Maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to run an external command may be through the [`exec-maven-plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html). See the example for how to bind execution to a phase of your build. A configuration like:

```
    <configuration>
      <executable>perl</executable>
      <arguments>
        <argument>src/main/bin/script.pl</argument>
        <argument>arg1</argument>
        ...
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
```

will run a script through Perl.